# NM can't find my wifi network

Tags: wifi, adapter, archlinux

I freshly installed arch linux and I have small problem with my networkmanager. I'm using networkmanager with nm-applet and I see plenty of wifi networks nerby, but just not mine. I have connection when I'm creating hotspot on my phone, I have connection when I connect ethernet cable to this router and my phone see wifi network from this router, but my desktop doesn't.
I'm using adapter TP-LINK TL-WN722N and Netia Spot router.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer was pretty simple - I needed to change frequency in my router.